# Python regex matching all set of words in path strings

Tags: python, pandas, regex, count

I have a dataframe like this:

```
        paths.modified

0   {'/user/withdraw/lnurl': {'operations': {'added': ['GET'], 'deleted': ['POST']}}}
1   {'/user/withdraw/lnurl': {'operations': {'added': ['POST'], 'deleted': ['GET']}}}
2   {'/user': {'operations': {'deleted': ['PUT']}}}
3   {'/user': {'operations': {'added': ['PUT']}}}
4   {'/leaderboard': {'operations': {'deleted': ['PUT']}}}
5   {'/dummy': {'operations': {'modified': {'GET': {'operationID': {'from': '', 'to': 'dummyGet'}}, 'PUT': {'operationID': {'from': '', 'to': 'dummyPut'}}}}}, '/file_response': {'operations': {'modified': {'GET': {'operationID': {'from': '', 'to': 'file_responseGet'}}}}}, '/html': {'operations': {'modified': {'POST': {'operationID': {'from': '', 'to': 'htmlPost'}}}}}, '/raw_json': {'operations': {'modified': {'GET': {'operationID': {'from': '', 'to': 'raw_jsonGet'}}}}}, '/solo-object': {'operations': {'modified': {'POST': {'operationID': {'from': '', 'to': 'solo_objectPost'}}}}}
6   {'/login/joule': {'operations': {'deleted': ['GET']}}}
7   {'/login/joule': {'operations': {'added': ['GET']}}}
8   {'/': {'operations': {'modified': {'GET': {'summary': {'from': 'Validates a Swagger/OpenAPI 2.0 or an OpenAPI 3.0 definition returning a valid/invalid badge', 'to': 'Validates a Swagger/OpenAPI 2.0 or an OpenAPI 3.x definition returning a valid/invalid badge'}, 'description': {'from': 'Validates a Swagger/OpenAPI 2.0 or an OpenAPI 3.0 definition provided via `url` parameter\nreturning a valid/invalid badge\n', 'to': 'Validates a Swagger/OpenAPI 2.0 or an OpenAPI 3.x definition provided via `url` parameter\nreturning a valid/invalid badge\n'}, 'parameters': {'added': {'query': ['resolve', 'resolveFully', 'validateInternalRefs', 'validateExternalRefs', 'resolveRequestBody', 'resolveCombinators', 'allowEmptyStrings', 'legacyYamlDeserialization', 'inferSchemaType', 'jsonSchemaValidation', 'legacyJsonSchemaValidation']}}}, 'POST': {'summary': {'from': 'Validates a Swagger/OpenAPI 2.0 or an OpenAPI 3.0 definition returning a valid/invalid badge', 'to': 'Validates a Swagger/OpenAPI 2.0 or an OpenAPI 3.x definition returning a valid/invalid badge'}, 'description': {'from': 'Validates a Swagger/OpenAPI 2.0 or an OpenAPI 3.0 definition provided in request body\nreturning a valid/invalid badge\n', 'to': 'Validates a Swagger/OpenAPI 2.0 or an OpenAPI 3.x definition provided in request body\nreturning a valid/invalid badge\n'}, 'parameters': {'added': {'query': ['resolve', 'resolveFully', 'validateInternalRefs', 'validateExternalRefs', 'resolveRequestBody', 'resolveCombinators', 'allowEmptyStrings', 'legacyYamlDeserialization', 'inferSchemaType', 'jsonSchemaValidation', 'legacyJsonSchemaValidation']}}}}}}, '/debug': {'operations': {'modified': {'GET': {'summary': {'from': 'Validates a Swagger/OpenAPI 2.0 or an OpenAPI 3.0 definition returning a validation response', 'to': 'Validates a Swagger/OpenAPI 2.0 or an OpenAPI 3.x definition returning a validation response'}, 'description': {'from': 'Validates a Swagger/OpenAPI 2.0 or an OpenAPI 3.0 definition provided via `url` parameter\nreturning a validation response containing any found validation errors\n', 'to': 'Validates a Swagger/OpenAPI 2.0 or an OpenAPI 3.x definition provided via `url` parameter\nreturning a validation response containing any found validation errors\n'}, 'parameters': {'added': {'query': ['resolve', 'resolveFully', 'validateInternalRefs', 'validateExternalRefs', 'resolveRequestBody', 'resolveCombinators', 'allowEmptyStrings', 'legacyYamlDeserialization', 'inferSchemaType', 'jsonSchemaValidation', 'legacyJsonSchemaValidation']}}}, 'POST': {'summary': {'from': 'Validates a Swagger/OpenAPI 2.0 or an OpenAPI 3.0 definition returning a validation response', 'to': 'Validates a Swagger/OpenAPI 2.0 or an OpenAPI 3.x definition returning a validation response'}, 'description': {'from': 'Validates a Swagger/OpenAPI 2.0 or an OpenAPI 3.0 definition provided via request body\nreturning a validation response containing any found validation errors\n', 'to': 'Validates a Swagger/OpenAPI 2.0 or an OpenAPI 3.x definition provided via request body\nreturning a validation response containing any found validation errors\n'}, 'parameters': {'added': {'query': ['resolve', 'resolveFully', 'validateInternalRefs', 'validateExternalRefs', 'resolveRequestBody', 'resolveCombinators', 'allowEmptyStrings', 'legacyYamlDeserialization', 'inferSchemaType', 'jsonSchemaValidation', 'legacyJsonSchemaValidation']}}}}}}} 
9   {'/{tenant}/forwarders/v2beta1/certificates': {'operations': {'modified': {'POST': {'requestBody': {'content': {'mediaTypeModified': {'application/json': {'schema': {'required': {'stringsdiff': {'added': ['pem']}}}}}}}}}}}}
```

I have a regex which is supposed to match only the start of the paths: so in the given df values like: `'/user/withdraw/lnurl'`, `'/user'`, `'/leaderboard'`, `'/'`, `'/{tenant}/forwarders/v2beta1/certificates'`.

This is my regex in python:

```
'[A-Za-z0-9\-\/{}]+'
```

It matches any string that contains a combination of alphanumeric characters, hyphens, forward slashes, and curly braces.All in all, it looks for strings that start and end with a single quote, and in between those quotes it allows any combination of the characters mentioned above.

But when I apply the pattern to this code:

```
import re

paths_column = paths['paths.modified']

pattern = r"'[A-Za-z0-9\-\/{}]+'"

paths_list = [re.findall(pattern, str(path_dict)) for path_dict in paths_column]

# count the number of paths for each row using list comprehension
count_list = [len(paths) for paths in paths_list]
paths['Paths_modified'] = count_list
```

It is catching the desired paths, but also all the other words such as operations,added, GET etc- which I don't want. I tested the regex in `regex101`, where it produces the match correctly, but it fails in the code for some reason I am unable to debug. Any suggestions on where I am going wrong?

Edit: I edited in the dataframe(the 5th value), where I have multiple paths in one string, which should be matched by the regex.

Comment: `re.findall(...)[0]` ?

Comment: Change your regular expression so that it must start with a slash: `'/[A-Za-z0-9\-\/{}]+'`

Comment: Or better yet, `re.search(...).groups()[0]` ?

Comment: Looks like stringified dicts. It might be cleaner to parse them using `ast.literal_eval` and getting the first key (along the lines of `df['your column'].apply(literal_eval).apply(lambda x: next(iter(x)))`) or, if you're in control of where the data comes from, don't stringify them in the first place.

Comment: Will there always be `{` before it? and `:` after it? If so - you could make the pattern stricter: `r"{\s*'((?=[^']*/)[^']+')(?=\s*:)"`

Comment: The `{` is only valid for the first path, but for the second and so on, the paths will always start with this format : `'tenant':` , it can be preceded or succeeded by a `/`

Comment: You could remove the `{` part then e.g. `r"'((?=[^']*/)[^']+)':"`

Comment: This then causes trouble in the example I mentioned in the answer below unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/[\w{}-]+` can you try this regex pattern and see if it working for your use case

Comment: This regex works well for most use cases, but there are certain instances such as `{'/file_response': {'operations': {'modified': {'GET': {'responses': {'modified': {'200': {'content': {'mediaTypeAdded': ['application/json'], 'mediaTypeDeleted': ['*/*']}}}}}}}}}`, in this it catches both `'/file_response'` as well as `/json` which is wrong.

Comment: @BrieMerryWeather So use this: `'/[A-Za-z0-9\-\/{}]+'`

Comment: it is still not working, i tried in regex101, for the case I mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

As the name suggests `re.findall()` finds all occurrences of the specified pattern. Use `re.search()` if you only want to access the first one.

Comment: The problem is there can be two paths in one string such as in this case: `{'/dummy': {'operations': {'modified': {'GET': {'operationID': {'from': '', 'to': 'dummyGet'}}, 'PUT': {'operationID': {'from': '', 'to': 'dummyPut'}}}}}, '/file_response': {'operations': {'modified': {'GET': {'operationID': {'from': '', 'to': 'file_responseGet'}}}}}`. In such cases it will miss the second path( `/file_response`)